# paste function in R loop

Tags: r, string

I am trying to remove the duplicates of a master dataset with respect to a column, using "assign" does not work, the piece of the code is the following

```
varlist <- unique(Master_Data$Composite)
for (var in varlist){
  assign(paste("Data_",var,sep=""),filter(paste("Data_",var,sep=""),     !is.na(paste("Data_",var,sep=""))$Composite.T.))
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>         no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"

This is done relatively easy in SAS Macro, but I am sure R has features of it. Perhaps this has already been answered, I searched but couldn't find working solutions.
Thanks alot in advance,
M.

Comment: Hi M.M.P., please provide a reproducable example of your data, It's not clear to me what your aim is.

Comment: are you using `filter` from `dplyr` package or `stats` package? The error comes from the use of filter: the first argumet refers to a variable that does not yet exists and that is referred as a string. It won't work. The first argument of filter has to be the data (except if it is in a piping chain)